# Wrong number of arguments in lambda

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

In my sinatra app I have the code of

```
haml :"page123", locals:
      {
        items: (my_data.sort ->(item1, item2){ item2[:date] <=> item1[:date]}), 
      }, 
      layout: need_layout?
```

What I need to do is to sort my_data by `date` in `descending` order. However, I' getting the error here

```
wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable#sort` does not take any arguments. You are essentially passing a `Lambda` object as the first and only argument to the `sort` method. What you can do is supply a block to be used to sort the collection.

`wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)` is saying that the method was given `1` argument and expected `0`.

Try this:

```
my_data.sort{ |a, b| b[:date] <=> a[:date] }
```

Comment: In fact, I'm passing lambda object, not proc.